# When was the second season of "The A List" filmed?

Tags: the-a-list

The two seasons of *The A-List* were *released* about three or four years apart. In-universe, not much time seems to have passed between the first season of *The A-List* and the second one: in the first episode, the protagonists say that they have been interned in the facility for six weeks, and Mia's certainly does not seem to act as if years have passed. Still, to my eyes the characters look rather older.

The first season was certainly filmed in 2018 or some time before that year, since that is when it premiered. The second season apparently was produced exclusively by Netflix, not by the BBC, which dropped out in 2019, so it would seem as if it must have been filmed in 2019 at the earliest. Filming during 2020 seems less probable for...obvious reasons, and 2021 would be a fairly quick turnaround.

So when was the second season filmed?